# Testcontainer Keycloak does not connect to Testcontainer PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, keycloak, testcontainers

I am deploying two Testcontainers, one with an image of PostgreSQL (12.0) and another one with Keycloak (8.0.0).

The PostgreSQL one starts successfully, but when the Keycloak one tries to connect to PostgreSQL returns a connection refused.

I put all the environment variables to Keycloak to connect to that PostgreSQL container

```
withEnv("DB_VENDOR", "postgres");
withEnv("DB_DATABASE", KeycloakDS);
withEnv("DB_SCHEMA", test);
withEnv("DB_USER", postgres);
withEnv("DB_PASSWORD", keycloak);
withEnv("DB_ADDR", postgres);
withEnv("DB_PORT", ${DB_PORT});
withEnv("KEYCLOAK_USER", admin);
withEnv("KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD", admin);
```

where ${DB_PORT} is the port where the PostgreSQL is deployed and the DB_ADDR is the alias that  PostgreSQL container has in a network that I made, where are both containers.

Am I missing something?
Has anyone tried too with success?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${DB_PORT}` must be `5432`, since you connect directly to the container and not through the exposed port.

Comment: But the environment variable that I am declaring into the Keycloak Container or the other one?

Comment: It works! Replacing the port of PostgreSQL assigned by Testcontainer for 5432. Thanks a lot!